# Dropdown - Values from other list depending on user input

Tags: 2013, list

I have a list which stores new user requests. In the form, there are fields for the wanted Operating system and the type (Notebook or Desktop). These are stored in the list and are radio buttons.

However, I have another list with all the models. This list has the columns "Name" (i.e. Lenovo T510), "Type" (Notebook or Desktop) and "OS" (Windows or Mac).

What I like to have is a dropdown menu showing the models. However, it should only show the models which are based on the selection of the user. So if the user chooses a Windows Notebook, the dropdown should only show the list entrys where "Type" is Notebook and "OS" is Windows.

I hope it is clear what I want to accomplish. Is there a way to do it? I have access to SharePoint Designer and jQuery to get this job done, so this isn't a problem. However, I like to solve this with as much default settings from SharePoint as possible.

This is in SharePoint 2013.

Thank you.

Comment: This is in no way different from countless questions on the same topic, which can be referred to as "cascading dropdowns". Try looking for questions containing this keyword

Comment: you need cascading lookup solution, perhaps it would be 3rd party tool, if you don't want to code it yourself.